# Hiding UITextField and that UITextField must function in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have downloaded one sample LinkedIn integration Code(iOS) from http://goo.gl/xLmhXb. Code is working fine.I am trying to hide the url bar which is UITextField. I am able hide the UITextFiled but it is not running in the background. Actually in that UITextFiled url get fetched dynamically at run time.The Fetching is not happening when I tried to hide textfiled but its not working. 
How to hide textfield and make it run in background.

```
- (void)initLinkedInApi

{
   apikey = @"787*******";
   secretkey = @"p5h******";   

   self.consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:apikey
                                       secret:secretkey
                                       realm:@"http://api.linkedin.com/"];

   requestTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
   accessTokenURLString = @"https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken";
   userLoginURLString = @"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize";    
   linkedInCallbackURL = @"hdlinked://linkedin/oauth";

   requestTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:requestTokenURLString] retain];
   accessTokenURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:accessTokenURLString] retain];
   userLoginURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:userLoginURLString] retain];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self initLinkedInApi];
   [addressBar setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
```

}

Those urls are loading into  UITextfield(i.e addressBar in this case).
What I am trying to do is hiding the textfield the and same the function mentioned above.But not getting!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, you are saying you are able to hide textfield but its running in background and asking how to hide it and make it run in background, that doesnt make any sense. Try to edit your question and add more details to it. What exactly do you want the textfild to do?

Comment: Sorry it is not running in the background. I have edited it. Please help me .

Comment: Ok, first of all, UITextField is an UIComponent that can be changed only on the main thread. Second I am pretty sure uitextfield is not downloading any data for you it simply cant. You still need to explain yourself better. You want to download some data from URL which is displayed in your textfield and you want to do it in background thread, is that it? If so, show some code so we know what do you have.